# Sage python bug in looped graph degree computation?

Tags: python, graph, immutability, sage

I'm working in Sage. Python appears to define degrees inconsistently for looped mutable/immutable graphs. This is screwing up my computations hard. What is going on here?

```
q=graphs.CompleteGraph(2)
q.allow_loops(True)
q.allow_multiple_edges(True)
q.add_edge([1,1])
a=q.copy(immutable=True)
b=q.copy(immutable=False)

sage: a==b
True
sage: a.degree()
[1, 2]
sage: b.degree()
[1, 3]
```

Comment: Can you see whether the fix at http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/17225 would be a good fix for your situation?  I believe that the "two degrees for a loop" is usual, but maybe not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nasty bug.  Here is why.

```
sage: a._backend
<class 'sage.graphs.base.static_sparse_backend.StaticSparseBackend'>
sage: b._backend
<class 'sage.graphs.base.sparse_graph.SparseGraphBackend'>
```

In the usual backend, there is code like this for undirected graphs.

```
    if self._loops and self.has_edge(v, v, None):
        if self._multiple_edges:
            d += len(self.get_edge_label(v, v))
        else:
            d += 1
```

In the static one, we just get

```
        else:
            return cg.out_degree(v)
```

Comment: I've reported this at http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/17225  Thanks for the report!

Comment: As a workaround, I guess you could try to make your graphs non-sparse and see what happens, or just stick with mutable graphs. (On the other hand, it probably wouldn't be too hard to try aping the code for the one in the other, if you are familiar with Sage development, but that would be for extra credit.)

Comment: Followup - this is fixed, and will likely be in Sage 6.5 in a month or two (or three).